# How to store scalar variables in perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array

```
my @numbers;
my $num1 = 23;
my $num2 = 4;
@numbers=(\$num1 ,\$num2);
print @numbers;
```

then on printing the array i get something like this SCALAR(0x6a16ec8), i want the values. How do i properly store the scalar values in the array?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need take reference of scalars by `\`. You can directly do:

```
@numbers = ($num1, $num2);
```

Comment: Note that this merely stores the *values* of the scalars in the array, but that's surely what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You stored a reference in your array.

```
@numbers=(\$num1 ,\$num2);
```

Delete the "\" in front of your Variables and it work.

```
@numbers=($num1 ,$num2);
```

---

A other simple Way is to use the push function from perl.

```
push(@numbers,($num1,$num2));
```

With push you append your array.